# Expo pop-up notifications (floating notifications) don't work on android

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

Notifications come but are displayed only in the status bar.

I use "expo": "~44.0.0" and "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0".

The code is completely copied from the documentation.

```html
import * as app from 'app.json';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import { Subscription } from 'expo-modules-core';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { ScreenView } from '@shared/components/screenView';


Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const notificationListener = useRef<unknown>();
  const responseListener = useRef<unknown>();

  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState<Notifications.Notification>();



  useEffect(() => {
    void registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => setToken(token ?? ''));
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
      setNotification(notification);
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });

  return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);



  return (
    <ScreenView alignItems="center">
    </ScreenView>
  );
};


async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;

  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
    });
  }

  return token;
}
```

I also added to app.json.

```
"useNextNotificationsApi": true
```

Previously with the "expo" versions: "~40.0.0" and "expo-notifications": "~0.8.2"  it worked

[Status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jodWA.jpg)

[Push notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFlGD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement in-app notification if the app is opened.
Check it out: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Comment: Thank you, I fully used the code from the documentation